# I want to be able to use only Alt+F4 when the shortcut keys are disabled in the WebBrowser of Form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As shown in the code below, when a WebBrowser is placed in a sub-window and the focus is on the WebBrowser in the sub-window, I want to close only the sub-window with Alt+F4, but somehow the parent form is also closed.
Why does this happen?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
    }

    public class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
            Controls.Add(webBrowser1);

            webBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
                    Close();
            };

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply remove that code. If you call `Close()` without suppressing the key press, it's bubbled up to the Form that is activated after. `ALT+F4` already closes the current Window by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the key as in input key without calling `Close`, then it will close the current window:

```
webBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: @ssa2 Don't miss Jimi's explanation about the root cause.

Comment: Yes, sir. Also, I misspelled "&&" as "&".